# Testing Azure Active Directory security locally

Tags: azure, single-page-application, azure-active-directory

I have a web application deployed on Azure with the Azure Active Directory security enabled (the express setting). So, when I try to access the application, I need to be a part of the AD to have access.

I would like to add more features to the application, like displaying the current user logged in, implement a logout, managing permissions etc... I believe I can achieve all of things with Azure Graph API.

However, to do this, I will need to test some stuff locally. Is there any way to simulate Azure AD locally? It is "switched on" on Azure and everything works great there, but ain't got nothing to simulate this on my local machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no "local" or "offline" version of Azure AD available.**

Your options at this time are:

- **Test using an actual Azure AD tenant**. You can create your own test tenant to allow you to make changes as necessary, postponing the need to work with the admin of your corporate Azure AD until you're ready to go to production.
- **Create your own Mock STS** that implements the OpenID Connect protocol and use that during development/testing. The risk here is that you'll have to make sure that this Mock STS behaves just like Azure AD does or close enough for your purposes.

As a side note, you can create a feedback entry asking for a feature on this in the [Azure AD Feedback Forum](http://aka.ms/aaduv)